# Голосовой чат на сайте на базе teamspeak

Tags: клиент, voip, чат, сервер

Существует ли готовый веб-клиент Teamspeak? Необходимо создать конференц-комнату и голосовое общение я хочу реализовать через сервер Teamspeak. Но так-как устанавливать на каждую машину клиентскую программу не вариант, то нужна веб версия. Чтобы можно было зайти на страницу, вписать имя и сразу присоединиться к чату, без всяких настроек.

Если такая штука существует скиньте информацию по установке и настройке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такой штуки там нет. Но есть Teamspeak 3 SDK, при помощи которого вы это сможете встроить в любой браузер сами!